# Zend 1.12 Zend/Form/Element -> addError() gives warning on line 2247 of Zend/FormI/Element

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form-element

**Environment:**
Apache 2.4
Windows 8
PHP 5.4.14
Zend 1.12

I am doing a very very very simple action on my form, adding an error message on one of my elements with:

```
$form->getElement('elemetnid')->addError('error');
```

It works wonders for everyone else, but on my case it *also* gives out a warning that reads:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...\library\Zend\Form\Element.php on line 2247
```

This only happens when I try to set the error on my MultiSelect element, but if I do so on another element like Text, then everything is great and no warning is given. So I went to inspect the line on the warning, and realized that the problem is that "getValue()" for that element is returning "NULL" and that is not a correct value for the foreach loop inside the framework´s code. But how is that my responsability?

My question is, if anyone knows how to add an error message for a multiSelect without this warning popping up.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you have an error message assigned to a multiselect element. It seems that with a multiselect, you supply the values, the user just chooses. Where is the potential for an error that requires a message to the user? Just asking...

Comment: If validation fails it will automatically add an error, do you just want to put a custom error message?

Comment: I am not using the multiselect as is, so I figured it's best to just create a custom validator. It´s the user who dynamically adds the multioptions, and he needs to add at least one in order to submit.

Answer (score 1):

I can't recreate your error with: Apache 2.2.16, Php 5.3.7 and Zf 1.12.5.

The behaviour is rather odd though.  If I invalidate an element before validating the form (by adding an error to an element), it looks like it short circuits the form validation and the error message does not get applied to the form output.

If I try and force in an invalid value via the URL, a value not in my multi-select, I get repeat error messages, and my previously set error messages override the 'X' was not found in the haystack message.

```
$form = new Zend_Form;
$form->setMethod('GET');

$listOptions = array('one','two', 'three');
$select = new Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect('options', array(
        'multiOptions' => $listOptions,
         'validators'   => array(
                array('InArray',
                      false,
                      array(array_keys($listOptions)))
            )
    ));
$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit', array(
        'label' => 'Do something'
    ));
$form->addElements(array($select, $submit));

if(isset($_GET) && count($_GET)) {
    if(true)
        $select
            ->addError('The form will never validate.')
            ->addError('Two wrongs don\'t make a right.');

    $form->isValid($_GET);
}

$form->setView(new Zend_View);
echo $form;

if ($form->isErrors()) {
    echo 'Form did not validate';
    var_dump($form->getErrors());
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this behavior is happening in ZF 1.12.5.